# ggplot chart to rChart chart

Tags: javascript, r, ggplot2, rcharts

I'd like to reproduce this chart [image: ggplot_chart]

with rCharts because i will hope to add tooltips. This is the code for this ggplot chart :

```
auto_cols <- sample(x = colors(), size = 96)
well_letters <- rep(LETTERS[1:8], each = 12)
tt <- data.frame(Well = factor(c(well_letters),rev(unique(well_letters))), 
       ncols = factor(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,
                        12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
                        11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
                        10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
                        9,10,11,12)),
       Gene_Symbol = factor(c(NA,"AUV1","AUV2","AUV3","AUV4","AUV5","AUV6","AUV7","AUV8","AUV9","AUV10",NA,NA,"AUV13","AUV14","AUV15","AUV16","AUV17","AUV18","AUV19","AUV20","AUV21","AUV22",NA,NA,"VH1","VH2","VH3","VH4","VH5","VH6","VH7","VH8","VH9","VH10",NA,NA,"GH3","GH4","GH5","GH6","GH7","GH8","GH9","GH10","GH11","GH12",NA,NA,"JUI2","JUI3","JUI4","JUI5","JUI6","JUI7","JUI8","JUI9","JUI10","JUI11",NA,NA,"BKJ2","BKJ3","BKJ4","BKJ5","BKJ6","BKJ7","BKJ8","BKJ9","BKJ10","BKJ11",NA,NA,"CVG3","CVG4","CVG5","CVG6","CVG7","CVG8","CVG9","CVG10","CVG11","CVG12",NA,NA,"GH40","GH41","GH42","GH43","GH44","GH45","GH46","GH47","GH48","GH49",NA)),
Sequence =(c(NA,"CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC",NA,NA,"CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC",NA,NA,"CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC",NA,NA,"CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC",NA,NA,"CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC",NA,NA,"CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC",NA,NA,"CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC",NA,NA,"CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC","CAUCUGACC",NA)),auto_cols = auto_cols)

ggplot(tt, aes(y = Well, x = ncols)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = Gene_Symbol), size =8) + 
  guides(col = guide_legend(nrow = 10, ncol = 10)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = auto_cols) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = Gene_Symbol, size = 150, vjust = 2), show_guide=FALSE) +
  xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL) + theme(legend.position="none")`
```

For rCharts graph i do something like this 
[image: rCharts_chart]

but isn't perfect !!

this is the rchart code

```
r1 <- rPlot(y = list(var='Well',sort="Well") ,x = 'ncols', 
        data = tt, type = "point", color = 'Gene_Symbol', size = list(const = 8),
        tooltip = "#! function(item){return 'Sequence :' + item.Sequence +'//'+'Gene_Symbol :'+ item.Gene_Symbol} !#")
r1$set(legendPosition = 'none')
r1$guides(x = c(min = 0, max = 13))
```

Someone can do better

Comment: For me its pretty good as it is. What do you lack or would you like to improve/change?

Comment: I prefer add gene_symbol on the plate and Sequence as tooltip

Comment: In my opinion achieving such a thing is complicated with the libraries available in rCharts. I have not found any example of scatterplots with labels or text boxes for NVD3, Polycharts, dimple or Rickshaw. If you know some d3.js the way to go may be making the scatterplot yourself. Here a scatterplot example by Scott Murray: goo.gl/vKRFDp Another option is using a shiny app and adding a tooltip to the ggplot. There is a small discussion on how to do that on the comments of this question: http://goo.gl/x69MS1